# New RAM -> memtest crash

Tags: laptop, memory

I bought two new RAM-sticks for my old laptop
**Toshiba Portege R700-19T**

But since I've installed them, the machine won't boot into an OS anymore.
The installed Windows 7 64bit goes to a black screen before the windows logo on startup (same with safe mode). And after a few seconds the fans are going fast but nothing seems to happen.

The next thing I tried was an ubuntu(12.04) live dvd. But this won't boot either. No error message or something, only an automatic restart after a few seconds of black screen.

Next thing was memtest86+ v4.20:
It crashes immediately sometimes to a black screen and sometimes to this [image: http://i.imgur.com/eJqIyDp.jpg].

I've tested my new two sticks together and alone, always the same problem. The old ones work perfectly and no crash from memtest.

In the BIOS is only one thing about memory and there it shows the correct "Total Memory Size 8192 MB"

laptop-mem specs from toshiba:

```
Standard : 4 (2 + 2) GB
max. Speicherausstattung : 8 GB
Technologie : DDR3 RAM (1.066 MHz)
```

[link to product description from Toshiba](http://www.toshiba.de/discontinued-products/portege-r700-19t/)

old (working) ram-sticks:

```
2x Samsung 2GB 1Rx8 PC3-10600S-09-10-ZZZ M471B5773CHS-CH9
```

new ram-sticks:

```
2x G.Skill 4GB DDR3-1333 (PC3-10600)
```

[link to shop where I bought it](https://www.alternate.de/G-Skill/SO-DIMM-8-GB-DDR3L-1333-Kit-Arbeitsspeicher/html/product/1154622)

In my understanding the two new sticks should work well with my laptop, or am I something missing?

To eliminate the posibillity, that the sticks are simply bad, I send them back to the vendor and got a pair of new ones (same model though). But the problem persist in the same way as before..

regards

Edit:
updated my bios to the newest version, but the error persists.

Comment: I would recommend updating the BIOS (if possible) and testing again - all indications suggest this configuration *should* work.

Comment: While I agree it should work.  I find it suspect that the original parts are labeled as `PC3-10600S` that indicates to me that they are not a standard PC3-10600 module.  The fact the modules are not even working with memtestx86 also indicates a true incompatibility between your system and the new memor modules.

Comment: I updated the Bios but the error persists..

Comment: You probably need to adjust the memory timings in the bios.  CL9 9-9-24